# car flooded from air conditioning

Tags: honda

my 2017 honda hrv was flooded inside when i went to drive it last week.  i thought due to heavy rain and contacted my insurance company and took it to the suggested auto body repair center geico adjuster recommended. after three weeks auto body stated it was actually due to defective air conditioning unit and some repairs were done at honda after the auto body cleaned out the water etc.  i had a $500 comprehensive deductible and i think honda should have to pay it since car still under warranty?

Comment: Well, does depend on what was "defective", some service items are not covered under warranty and that may include the a/c moisture or condensate drain being blocked... May need to check the paperwork and with a lawyer...